# Thymeleaf - passing models in JAVA

Tags: java, spring, list, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to create a simple webpage, in which animals have some properties (like name, animalType, and balance) using Thymeleaf. However, I've been suffering from the proper syntax.

My Java code is:

```
   @GetMapping("/multipleaccounts")
   public String multiple(Model model) {
   List bankAccounts = new ArrayList<>();
   model.addAttribute("account", bankAccounts);
   return "multiple";
   }
```

The problematic part of my thymeleaf code at the /multipleaccounts endpoint:

```
<div th:each="element : ${account}" th:object="${element}">
    <p th:text="|My name is *{name}|"></p>
    <p th:text="|My balance is *{balance}|"></p>
    <p th:text="|My type is *{animalType}|"></p>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you not use the raw types but rather `List<Account>` or similar.

To iterate the `List` in Thymeleaf template, please see the [Baeldung's webpage](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-iteration) where is this issue properly explained.

In a nutshell, the correct notation with the string concatenation is the following:

```
<div th:each="a: ${account}">
    <p th:text="'|My name is ' + ${a.name} + '|'"></p>
    <p th:text="'|My balance is ' + ${a.balance} + '|'"></p>
     <p th:text="|My type is ' + ${a.animalType} + '|'"></p>
</div>
```

By the way, are you sure that each account has `animalType`?

Comment: Thank you!

Basically my solution was working, I just forgot to add items to the list, from which I wanted to take out some elements.

I will take attention for your pieces of advice, though.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This will helps you:

```
<div th:each="element : ${account}">
    <p th:text="'|My name is ' + ${element.name} + '|'"></p>
    <p th:text="'|My balance is ' + ${element.balance} + '|'"></p>
    <p th:text="'|My type is ' + ${element.animalType} + '|'"></p>
</div>
```